# Does ExtractData in MySQL support namespaces?

Tags: mysql, xml, xpath

I have a very large xml file which I have stored in a longtext field called xml, in a table called imports.

Then I store todays xml string in a user variable called @xml like this.

```
SELECT xml FROM imports WHERE DATE(updated_at) = DATE(NOW()) INTO @xml;
```

I can test the user variable and the length of the data is there as expected.

```
SELECT LENGTH(@xml);
```

Testing the position of my target xml tag also works as expected.

```
SELECT LOCATE('sm:ProductCode>', @xml);
```

However when I try to use the ExtractValue with an XPath query that contains the namespace, I get null. This XPath query is tested and working fine in my XPath exploring software.

```
SELECT ExtractValue(@xml, '//sm:ProductCode');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is supported as of 5.1.10:

> Beginning with MySQL 5.1.10, XPath expressions passed as arguments to ExtractValue() and UpdateXML() may contain the colon character (“:”) in element selectors, which enables their use with markup employing XML namespaces notation.

If your version is older, then there's nothing you can do, the XPath `namespace-uri()` function, that you could have used as a workaround, is not supported.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I'm using 5.1.41, I've also tested on 5.5.14

I read about the support for the : character but there is so little documentation available I thought maybe I was hitting a limitation of this feature.

Is there a way to tell MySQL that the data contained in @xml is xml? All string functions work fine, but XPath just returns null.